# Why does Internet Explorer (or other browsers) use old JavaScript files when I try to debug my ASP.NET program?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I'm changing a .js JavaScript file in my ASP.NET MVC 5 solution, but when I go to debug the program, Internet Explorer 11 frequently loads old JavaScript files (caught chrome doing it too ). What is the problem here, some setting I'm missing? Even if it has the cached JavaScript file in its cache, shouldn't it load the new one with the newer modified date?

Comment: Dynamically add something like `file.js?v=00013` to your paths to simply avoid the problem.

Comment: We should all sign a petition to ban IE from the face of the earth. It is always a nightmare to work with. :)

Comment: 'Even if it has the cached javascript file in its cache, shouldn't it load the new one with the newer modified date?' I don't think so. It will live in the cache as long as the server told it to keep it there with the Expires HTTP Response header. From there it wouldn't bother checking to see if there is a newer copy because it already has one.

Comment: Try clearing the cache by using Ctrl + F5 in the browser when you refresh the page.

Comment: Whenever facing such issues with a browser, try opening the same link in a fresh private browsing session for the same browser. If the old file is still served, then problem is on server side, else it is the client (the browser) which is playing some caching mischief.

Comment: Reading the http 1.1 spec it appears caching is more complicated that it appears.

Comment: "Did you try turning it off and back on again" applies to web browsers too. Start with closing the browser and re-opening it. Sucks, i know, but it usually solves such problems.

Comment: Now the problem disappeared and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either read http://fiddler2.com/r/?httpperf to learn how browsers implement caching, or you can simply hit CTRL+F5 to get IE to bypass the cache.

IE cannot magically "know" that the server has a newer version without asking for it, which would defeat the purpose of having a cache in the first place.

Comment: Since disabling web essentials toolkit I haven't seen the problem anymore. My view of caching is to prevent file transfer through not modified HTTP response.

Comment: But yeah it seems you can configure it not to even check for the new version unless some time has passed.

Comment: @IBC: No, that's not how that works. You should read the article I pointed to understand how caching and the caching settings really function.

Comment: You'd think that a hash of the file could be done and so that hash can just be checked each time. Yes, it's still a check but it's minimal. Who doesn't have high speed internet anyway. Is caching really required anymore? I mean a 12k file can be downloaded pretty damn fast over a 50 Mbps pipe.

Comment: @user441521: If you assume everyone is on a 50mbps pipe, you're making a foolish assumption. You should look up ETAGs to understand how conditional revalidation requests work.

Answer (score 1):

change the setting via tools ->Internet options -> advanced -> enable the option empty internet temporary files folder when browser is closed

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In explorer settings set the property to get files every time you visit the page.